# using jquery click function to target a link with jquery show/hide doesn't work in firefox and ie but works in safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the following jquery to show/hide on div to reveal text and then disappear again. The div can be reopened when you click on it. I have a link inside the text and are using jquery to target the 'a' link which works fine in safari but not in firefox or ie. I do get an error with error console in firefox with ReferenceError: event is not defined so have tried placing the actual url in but that is not working for me either.

```
var isOn = true;
function getOff() {
    if (isOn) {
        $("#button").trigger('click');
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").toggle(function() {
        $("#expandText").show("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, 1000);
        $("#button").css("background-image", "url(images/Text_Expander_off.jpg)");
    }, function() {
        $("#expandText").hide("slide", {
            direction: "left"
        }, 1000);
        $("#button").css("background-image", "url(images/Text_Expander_on.jpg)");
    });

    $("a").click(function() { //Onclick <a></a>
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        window.location = url;
    });
    $("#button").trigger('click');
    setTimeout("getOff()", 5000);
});​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you simply need to change this line:

```
$("a").click(function() {
```

to

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
```